# Скопировать файл в несколько потоков в .net 3.5

Tags: c#

Возможно ли скопировать файл в несколько потоков? Если да, то как? Я пытаюсь сделать что-то подобное, но оно ожидаемо не работает:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyProgramm
{
    class Copymaker
    {
        private int v_buffer_size;
        FileStream input;
        FileStream output;

        public Thread thread1;
        public Thread thread2;


        public Copymaker(int buffer_size)
        {
            this.v_buffer_size = buffer_size;
        }

        public void Copy(FileInfo fileToCopy)
        {

            using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCopy.OpenRead())
            {
                using (FileStream copiedFileStream = File.Create(fileToCompress.FullName + ".new"))
                {
                    input = originalFileStream;
                    output = copiedFileStream;
                    thread1 = new Thread(CopyBuffer);
                    thread1.Start();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("End?");
            }
        }

        private void CopyBuffer()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[v_buffer_size];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В таком виде, конечно, не работает. Даже поток не запускается (говорит, нет доступа к закрытому потоку). Что я понимаю не верно?

Comment: Вы сами диспозите FileStream'ы при помощи `using` блока. Поэтому когда начинает выполнятся код из потока, они уже закрыты.

Answer (score 3):

> Возможно ли скопировать файл в несколько потоков? Если да, то как?

Возможно. Например, именно так и делает Utorrent. Он сначала резервирует область памяти на винчестере а потом в куче потоков скачивает его из интернета когда это становится возможным (когда на раздаче кто-то появляется) и потом на определенную область зарезервированной памяти вносит изменения в виде бинарного кода с этой же области у оригинального файла из интернета.

---

А теперь перейдем к НЕЗАДАННОМУ вопросу: **Имеет ли это смысл?**

Распараллеливание дает прирост скорости исключительно на работе с CPU/GPU. Т.к. поток имеет свои ограничения, но незадействованного ресурса у CPU/GPU еще достаточно.

Но копирование, это работа с HDD. Работа с HDD не станет быстрее если копировать файл в несколько потоков. Она станет МЕДЛЕННЕЕ.

Почему?

Да потому, что HDD работает на основе физики и ты упрешься в возможности механики винчестера. Там есть читающая головка и есть "блин" который крутится с некоей скоростью. Именно по этому у HDD самая высокая скорость записи или чтения -- последовательная. То есть если на блине записаны данные последовательно -- чтение будет быстрым(относительно рандомно размещенных данных). Если нет -- головку нужно перемещать из одной позиции на другую. Распараллеливание задачи копирования сделает так, что головку нужно будет перемещать чаще(логично, не так ли?).

В случае с SSD ты не получишь замедления копирования. Но так же и прироста не получишь. Там нету механики, а это дает высокую скорость чтения/записи рандомно размещенных данных. Зато все равно есть ограничение по скорости. То есть точно так же... Ты хоть последовательно копируй данные, хоть параллельно -- ты получишь идентичную скорость.

А что если копировать через сеть? Например через Ethernet-кабель, получим ли мы желаемый профит?
Снова таки нет. Мы упремся в ограничения скорости кабеля. Как упирались в скорость SSD.

А теперь когда мы выяснили что это возможно, но бессмысленно....

Стоит ли решать данную задачу тобой или кем-либо в принципе?)

---

1. Резервируешь место под будущий файл нужного размера
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416413/create-new-file-with-specific-size
2. Создаешь метод для считывания: адрес файла, начальный байт, конечный байт. Ну или читалку которая считывает с оффсетом. Например такую: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208592/reading-parts-of-large-files-from-drive
3. Метод для обработки данных (что там тебе нужно с ними сделать я не знаю, но ты писал что это не просто копирование). Стоит учесть что я не знаю изменяется ли количество данных или нет, если изменяется хотя бы на один байт -- это стоит учитывать при записи в конечный файл.
4. метод для записи в конечный файл (адрес файла, начальный байт). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529313/write-byte-array-to-middle-of-an-existing-file-in-c-net
5. Вызываешь нужное количество потоков с вызовом этих методов. Можно попробовать как через таски так и через трэды.

Comment: Стоит. Я ведь спросил не праздного интереса ради и только узкую подзадачу. В реальной задаче каждый кусок файла еще и обрабатывается, еще и на различных процессорах, поэтому скорость упирается далеко не в шину и не в носитель. И мне, признать по правде, совсем не до смеха.

Comment: ну тогда действуй по тому принципу,который описан в начале ответа -- как это делает utorrent.

Comment: Не обижайтесь, но это слишком общее описание. Как на вопрос "Как построить дом" ответить "Ну рубишь лес, складываешь стены, а потом крышу сверху". Правдиво, очевидно, но без прикладного значения.

Comment: не знаю что было непонятно с того описания и почему оно тебе общим показалось, но я насписал детальнее. Хотя как по мне, то это детальное описание абсолютно логично выплывает из того общего и без уточнений.

Comment: Переход к ооп после баз данных для меня в новинку и то, что кажется вам очевидным для новичка таким вовсе не кажется. Спасибо за дополнения.

Comment: Вообще если учитывать что я не знаю как данные обрабатываются это может быть неправильным ответом. Но на то количество информации которое ты дал -- точнее никто тебе не ответит. :)

Comment: Так и не понимаю зачем вам параллельно писать все это. Сделайте по стандартной схеме Производитель/Потребитель. Пусть у вас будет несколько производителей(CPU), которые будут говорить "Я сделал некоторую работу, запиши ее пожалуйста" и класть это в какую-то коллекцию. Поток будет брать все это и поочередно писать. Вот.

Comment: кстате да, iluxa1810 прав. Меня что-то сбило с толку. И вправду достаточно и последовательной записи.

Answer (score 0):

> Возможно ли скопировать файл в несколько потоков? Если да, то как?

Не вижу смысла в нескольких потоках на запись.
Пусть даже вы и параллельно делаете какую-то работу, но пишущий поток должен быть только 1. Исключение, если вы пишите на разные физические диски.

Реализуйте логику через паттерн Производитель/Потребитель, где производитель- это множество вычислительных потоков, которые результаты своей работы ставят в какую-то потокобезопасную очередь, а потом потребитель- это пишущий поток, который поочередно извлекает блоки данных и пишет их на диск.