# Многопоточность и сериализация

Tags: c#, многопоточность, асинхронность, task, десериализация

Такой вопрос, как можно осуществить многопоточную десериализацию/сериализацию? Асинхронная понятно, с этим проблем нет. Но я бы хотел выделить скажем в зависимости от количества записей некоторое количество потоков под запись(чтение).

Т.е., к примеру у меня есть 2000 записей в файле xml/json, и я хочу выделить два потока которые бы десериализовали/сериализовали файл. Результат должен быть совмещен.

Если по совмещению еще что-то понятно, то как приспособить многопоточность нет.

Примерная задумка совмещение: по имени/идентификатору потока, я говорю потоку читай только 1000 записей начиная с 0, а второму с 1000 записи тоже тысячу, а там просто list Concate произвести. Ну и понятное дело проверка на, то что потоки завершились (в данном случае, я скорее кстати разбираю вариант не Thread, a Task).

Спасибо за внимание к данному вопросу. Жду ваших предложение)

Comment: [многопоточность != async/await](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/491632/220553)

Comment: Так делайте вашу примерную задумку, не понимаю, в чем проблема

Comment: вот здесь я обьяснял почему безсмысленно так делать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933503/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-net-3-5/933513?noredirect=1#comment1548359_933513  (формально, аргументы почему это безсмысленно будут точно такими же)

Comment: Кроме того, что чтение с накопителя выполняется последовательно и, следовательно, его нельзя распараллелить, есть и другая проблема: в файле xml нельзя перейти к произвольной записи. Чтобы найти запись №1000, нужно предварительно просканировать (то бишь распарсить), первые 999 записей. А если они уже разобраны, то почему бы не продолжить обработку далее в этом же потоке?

Comment: Чисто теоретически, можно извратиться и создать такой формат хранения xml, который будет или иметь все узлы одного размера (ценой большего размера), или содержать позицию потока нужного (тысячного) узла, что даст возможность сделать вашу хотелку. Но, во-первых, это нужно делать предварительно, при записи файла, ценой лишних расходов. Во-вторых, это неприменимо, если вы работаете с файлами, получаемыми извне. В-третьих, это, по сути, реализация своей микро базы данных. Так почему бы не взять готовую подходящую СУБД?

Comment: EvgeniyZ, вы уверены что вы прочитали вопрос??? Где я сказал, что асинхронность есть многопоточность? Я сказал, что асинхронную запись/чтение я могу осуществить, асинхронную на одном потоке. Так что, читайте внимательно.